# amDateFormat is clobbering amTimezone in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

My code is as follows with the angular-moment package installed:

```
<td data-ng-bind="'2019-02-04T13:42:06.927+00:00' | amTimezone:'America/Halifax' | amDateFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A'"></td>
```

That code outputs: "02/04/2019 01:42 PM"

When I run the above code with out the amDateFormat filter I get:
"Mon Feb 04 2019 09:42:06 GMT-0400"

So I know each filter is working, but after doing some debugging on the angular-moment.js file, the preprocessDate call it what is clobbering my timezone information.

```
.filter('amDateFormat', ['moment', 'amMoment', 'angularMomentConfig', function (moment, amMoment, angularMomentConfig) {
                function amDateFormatFilter(value, format) {
                    if (isUndefinedOrNull(value)) {
                        return '';
                    }

                    var date = amMoment.preprocessDate(value);
                    if (!date.isValid()) {
                        return '';
                    }

                    return date.format(format);
                }

                amDateFormatFilter.$stateful = angularMomentConfig.statefulFilters;

                return amDateFormatFilter;
            }])
```

I have preprocess set to null in my angularMomentConfig of my angular-moment.js file, but it is running createUTC() from moment.js as a preprocessor function.

I have no idea how that function is being called or if that is the what is causing my issue, but any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
We had set a preprocessor in the core module that I hadn't looked at.

```
.constant('angularMomentConfig', {
    preprocess: moment.utc
  })
```

Removing that allowed it to work correctly.